# What have I calculated? Integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I've got $$D = \{(x,y) \in R^2 : (x-1)^2+y^2<=1, (x-2)^2+y^2<=4\}$$
Which basically are two basically two circles. I tried to calculate the area of the $$(x-1)^2+y^2<=1$$
Using polar-coordinates:
$$x = rcos\phi , y=rsin\phi$$

$$\int_{1}^{2}dr \int_{0}^{2\pi}((rcos\phi-1)^2+r^2sin^2\phi-1)d\phi$$
and I got
$$\frac{14}{3}\pi$$

But, what did I actually calculated?

Comment: The area is just $2\pi$ for the are you want to calculate : it is a translated circle of radius 1.

Answer (score 1):

You shall use the substitution :

$$ dxdy \sim rdrd\theta $$ instead of $$ drd\theta $$ that you have used.

Comment: Jacobian... how could I forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the volume below the following surface:

$$ \gamma(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2-1$$

For understanding this you can think that you use two parameters for your integral your resulting function (here $\gamma$) will generate a surface in 3D.